# Политика в Ларавеле принимает строку вместо модели

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь настроить доступ для редактирования пользователей, т.е. чтобы админ видел всех пользователей и мог менять их данные, а контент менеджер - только себя.
Создал политику и в ней такие 2 функции:

```
public function before(User $user, $var){
    if ($user->access=='admin') {
        return true;
    }
}

public function view(User $current_user, User $user)
{
    //$user = Auth::user();
    if ($current_user->id===$user->id) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

в шаблоне прописал следующее:

```
@foreach(\App\User::all() as $user)
    @can('view',$user)
        @include('manager.users.user')
    @endif
@endforeach
```

По непонятной мне причине, дебаггер показывает, что в качестве второй переменной, в первую функцию приходит строка "view".

Что я упускаю?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что я не убрал посредника в маршрутах.